# How do I experience my app as a user would? Can't replicate a crash just by compiling it

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, cocoa-touch, app-store-connect

So normally I compile my code into my app and it runs right on my device, but one user is claiming a crash and has very specific reproduction steps.

How do I install it as they'd see it? I know there's different debug vs production profiles with apps, so how would I do "production" I suppose?

I tried to "Archive" it as I would for uploading to iTunes, but exporting it instead of uploading, but when I try to install the IPA to my iPhone with Xcode > Devices window, it keeps saying "Internal API error" so I assume I'm doing something wrong

Comment: You can use a TestFlight build

Comment: Why not install the app from the App Store just as the user did?